# How do I make my page link open only on one side of the split screen?

Tags: html

I wanted to make a split screen that shows two separate pages open on each side (left/right). But whenever I click it, it just goes to one page how do I fix this?

HTML

```html
<div class="row no-gutters">

        <div class="col-md-6 no-gutters">
                <div class="leftside">
                        <div class="centered">
                        <a href="page1.md">Page 1</a>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 no-gutters">
                <div class="rightside">
                        <div class="centered">
                        <a href="page2.md">Page 2</a>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking the link simply opens the page, like a link should.

If you want to show the page inside your window, use an iFrame

```
<iframe src="page.md"></iframe>
```